# More flagging options needed

Tags: feature-request, moderation, flagging

This site has a relatively large amount of off-topic questions which should be better moved to SO or CV. But currently in Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic > Migration, the only listed site is meta-datascience. How can we suggest more related sites for this page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We add additional migration paths (that is, paths visible to users via the flag or close menu) once there is a demonstrated need for them. Basically, we look at the volume of posts being migrated, and when it starts to create a burden on moderators--who have to handle the flags and migrate the posts manually--we think about adding new paths.

Data Science is not at that threshold with migrations to any site. It has 5 migrations to Cross Validated in the past 90 days, with a 20% rejection rate. At this activity level it is more prudent to keep migration a manual process, since it is not a great burden on the moderation squad.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* that you will only see options to migrate to sites that you have some minimum reputation on. Moderators can migrate to any site. At least that difference appears to hold up looking at what I see here vs SO. So you can flag it as off topic and write in the site you think it belongs on, and a mod can migrate it if he/she agrees.